# Kohana form validation with orm and external captcha rule

Tags: validation, orm, kohana, external, captcha

I'm trying to add external validation rule for captcha like this:

```
$extra_rules = Validation::factory($_POST)
                    ->rule('captcha',  array(Captcha::valid($_POST['captcha'])));
```

I think the valid function is running but then I get this error:

> ```
> ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined offset: 1
> SYSPATH/classes/Kohana/Validation.php [ 376 ]
> ```

```
371                     // Replace with bound value
372                     $rule[0] = $this->_bound[$rule[0]];
373                     }
374 
375                     // This is an array callback, the method name is the error name
376                     $error_name = $rule[1];
377                     $passed = call_user_func_array($rule, $params);
```

Please help. I don't know how to manage this captcha validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not properly defining the validation rule, try this:

```
$extra_rules = Validation::factory($this->request->post())
                ->rule('captcha',  'Captcha::valid'));
```

Also, because of Kohana v3.+ HMVC capabilities, use of the `$_POST` superglobal is discouraged and using `$this->request->post()` is the recommended practice.

Comment: This works. Thank You. But I don't understand this $_POST part of the answer. Does it mean that I should use $this->request->post() to get values of form? How for example shoud I get $_POST['email'] with $this->request->post()?

Comment: $_POST['email'] would be accessed as $this->request->post('email'). If the key does not exist $this->request->post() will return NULL. 
http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Request#post